# Data and contents of HTML is getting lost after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, html

I am making an ajax call as mentioned below. I am developing a simple unsubscribe form where a user enters email and gets unsubscribed from mail alerts.
Using django framework

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="errorDiv"></div>
    <form id="unsubscribeform" class="unsubscribeform" method="POST" action="{% url 'polls:unsubscribe' %}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label class="required" for="emailUnsubscription">Email</label>
        <input id="emailUnsubscription" name="unsubscribeEmail" type="email"><br><br>
        <input value="unsubscribe" class="submit" id="submit" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.submit').bind('click', function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form_data = new FormData($(".unsubscribeform")[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:"?ajax=1",
                    data:form_data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        var resp = response;
                        var noUserError = response.nouser;
                        var emptyEmailError = response.emptyemail;
                        if(typeof emptyEmailError === 'undefined' && typeof noUserError === 'undefined'){
                            $(.submit).unbind('click').submit();
                        }else{
                            if(typeof emptyEmailError === 'undefined')
                                emptyEmailError = "";
                            if(typeof noUserError === 'undefined')
                                noUserError = "";
                            $(".errorlist").remove();
                            console.log(noUserError, emptyEmailError);
                            $("errorDiv").append('<span class="errorlist"><br>'+Please correct following errors+'</span>');
                            $("errorDiv").append('<span class="errorlist"><br>'+noUserError+'</span>');
                            $("errorDiv").append('<span class="errorlist"><br>'+emptyEmailError+'</span>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

after successfully returning my form in the html is getting lost and i get only a plain html with the json returned.

The following text is displayed in browser after ajax call

```
{"nouser": "No user exists with given email id"}
```

What am i doing wrong here

Comment: can you show also the php side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code to following

```
$('.submit').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ....

});
```

Comment: To elaborate on this answer `event.preventDefault` prevents the click on your button from going through normally after the click handler finishes. More details: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: As per your code, you are doing `$(elemid).bind('submit', function()` this inside click event. This seems unnecessary. Please remove this binding and try.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: @nikhil I have updated my code as suggested by you. But still i am getting the same result

Comment: I have 2 more concerns. Firstly, your url is `?ajax=1`, is it correct? Secondly, for AJAX, you have success callback but no error callback. Try adding that too. Additionally, please do not update your question again and again as for anyone who will be referring the question now, will find my answer same as question and irrelevant. If you want to update, update it under update heading block